# I want to create an issue in jira using jenkins pipeline but not with any plugin, is there a way to do so?

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline, jira, jira-rest-api

here is how the stage in my pipeline looks like

```
 stage('jira'){
             steps{
           bat 'curl --request POST  --url 'https://ID.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue'  --user 'mail@gmail.com:<token>'  --header 'Accept: application/json'  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  --data '{"fields": {"project":{"key": "FIT"},"summary": "created for j","description": "Created for j","issuetype": {"name": "Task"}}}''
                 }
        }
```

and here is what the error looks like

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 64: expecting '}', found ':'
```

if anyone knows any other way to achieve this in pipeline then please tell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You need to use escape characters for nested single quotes.

> You can use the Jenkins Syntax generator to produce this.  The syntax generator is located at https://< base-url >.com/pipeline-syntax/

```
stage('jira') {
    steps {
        bat 'curl --request POST  --url \'https://ID.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue\'  --user \'mail@gmail.com:<token>\'  --header \'Accept: application/json\'  --header \'Content-Type: application/json\'  --data \'{"fields": {"project":{"key": "FIT"},"summary": "created for j","description": "Created for j","issuetype": {"name": "Task"}}}'
    }
}
```

Comment: thank-you, this solved the error but somehow this command is not able to create the issue in jira, i have also used this code snippet `curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/` provided on atlassion site

Comment: What was he answer?

Comment: `curl -D- -u username:token -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"FIT\"},\"summary\":\"created for j\",\"description\":\"Created for j\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Task\"}}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://himanshu.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/'`

Comment: this code is working fine when i run it through windows cmd but when i put this in a pipeline like this `bat """curl -D- -u username:token -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"FIT\"},\"summary\":\"created for j\",\"description\":\"Created for j\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Task\"}}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://himanshu.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/'"""`

Comment: then its not working and throwing this error `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: for
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'C'` and also this `{"errorMessages":["Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@10bda120; line: 1, column: 3]"]}` . if you have any solution for this, please tell.

Comment: Why do you have a single quote at the end of the endpoint string? api/2/issue/'

Comment: It's here in the comments only by mistake , not in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :). Thank you.

You need to remove the single ' at the end, `https://himanshu.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/'"""` then it will looks like below. Use it and try, definitley it will work.

bat

```
curl -D- -u username:token -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"FIT\"},\"summary\":\"created for j\",\"description\":\"Created for j\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Task\"}}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://himanshu.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/"""
```